# KeyDown and KeyUp event

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I've been using GetASyncKeyState & !GetASyncKeyState but it doesn't respond well since the key I'm looking to track is being held down for a while before releasing.

I need to be able to hold down my Mouse1 button, and then fire an event when the button is released.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645533(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Silicomancer Nope, the (imaginary) question asks for mouse events.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: There are virtual key codes for mouse buttons too.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it, thanks for trying to help anyways.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MouseHookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT k = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)(lParam);
POINT p;

if (wParam == WM_LBUTTONUP)
{
    _bAimed = false;
}
return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

//...

MouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, MouseHookProc, hInstance, 0);

//...

while (1)
{
MSG msg;
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
}
```